# Singular ODEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a system of singular ODEs:

```
eq1 =  y1'[x] y1[x] - x y1'[x]^2 + x y1''[x] y1[x] == c1 y2[x];
eq2 = y2'[x] y2[x] - x y2'[x]^2 + x y2''[x] y2[x] == c2 y1[x];
```

This system has a regular (at $x = 0$) analytical solution:

$y_1(x) = 1 + c_1 x + \frac{1}{4} c_1 c_2 x^2, \quad 
y_2(x) = 1 + c_2 x + \frac{1}{4} c_1 c_2 x^2$.

However, I am unable to use NDSolve to find this solution. I am trying to do the following:

```
c1 = 0.25;
c2 = 0.5;

NDSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, y1[0] ==  1, y2[0] == 1, y1'[0] == c1, y2'[0] == c2}, 
{y1, y2}, {x, 0, 1000}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

But I arrive at

```
NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function 
within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and 
derivatives of the functions. >>
```

I am trying to use "Residual" method because equations are singular at $x = 0$.
I also do not understand why NDSolve cannot 'find' (?) initial conditions that satisfy the residual function. What does it mean? I am giving these conditions explicitly, but it asks me to give initial conditions for both values and derivatives which I exactly do.

I tried to avoid point $x = 0$ by setting some epsilon, say

```
eps = 0.00000001
```

and start integrating from this point (with initial conditions on eps provided), but it does not help.

Can anybody tell me how I could resolve this problem and integrate this system successfully using the NDSolve function?

Comment: You have `==` in your equations twice. Once in your definitions, and then again when you set them equal to zero.

Comment: With @aardvark2012's fix, everything seems to work fine.  No errors, solution returned.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ParametricNDSolve! Because of the parameters c1, c2 N(umerical!)DSolve can't solve the problem:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq1 , eq2 , 
y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 1, y1'[0] == c1, y2'[0] == c2},
{y1, y2}, {x, 0, 1000}, {c1, c2},
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"},AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

With give c1 = 0.25;c2 = 0.5;  NDSolve finds the solution directly:

```
erg = NDSolve[{eq1 , eq2 , y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 1, y1'[0] == c1, 
y2'[0] == c2}, {y1, y2}, {x, 0, 1000}, 
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 10]
Plot[{y1[x], y2[x]} /. erg[[1]]  , {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Plot initial condition]

without error. The initial conditions are as requested!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I fixed  the values c1 and c2. What might be wrong?..

Comment: Nevertheless, if I use ParametricNDSolve and substitute the values of parameters that I used in the question, I get the same error: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function \
within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both \
values and derivatives of the functions.

Comment: `Clear[c1,c2]` before using ParametricNDSolve.  Then define their values before using the NDSolve part.  Worked for me.